# C++ std::tm returns wrong value after converting it from std::chrono::time_point

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

**TL;DR:** How to use a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` to compare based on only certain parameters (e.g. I just want hours, minutes and seconds, but not day, month, etc.).

Also: After converting the `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` to a `std::tm`, the `std::tm.tm_hours` contains a value one higher than originally input to the `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.

---

My theoretical approach on getting a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` to work:

```cpp
typedef std::chrono::system_clock::time_point TimePoint;
```

```cpp
TimePoint MainWindow::createTimePoint(int h, int m)
{
    TimePoint createdTime = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point{std::chrono::hours(h) + std::chrono::minutes(m)};

    time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(createdTime);
    tm timeExtracted = *localtime(&tt);

    std::cout << "input:\t\t" << "H = " << h << ", M = " << m << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "timeExtracted:\t" << "H = " << timeExtracted.tm_hour << ", M = " << timeExtracted.tm_min << std::endl; 

    return createdTime;
}
```

If I run this, the hours of `timeExtracted` are always +1 from the input `h`.

**Why is that so? And how to fix this?** I went over a few other posts that showed this, but they couldnt help me. Probably also because of this:

I think that when I create a `TimePoint`, the day, month, etc. is also set to a random value or initiated to a certain value. The point is: I want them to always be the same value, so that my `TimePoint` (after converting) basically shows this:

```
timeExtracted.tm_sec = 0
timeExtracted.tm_min = m
timeExtracted.tm_hour = h
timeExtracted.tm_mon = 0
timeExtracted.tm_wday = 0
timeExtracted.tm_mday = 0
timeExtracted.tm_yday = 0
timeExtracted.tm_year = 0
timeExtracted.tm_isdst = 0
```

How can I compare two of these `TimePoint` utilising using the compare operations of std::chrono on them, but only compare the hour and minute.

---

If my question is unclear, I'm sorry, it's late in the evening. I'll check again next morning. Thank you.

Comment: What time zone are you in?  The first thing I always look at with weird time related behavior is if there's something from a locale/time zone causing problems.

Comment: When you talk of "fields" such as hour and minute, do you mean in your local time zone?  Because `system_clock` is UTC.  If comparing in UTC is ok, that's one answer.  If you need to compare in your local time zone, that's another answer.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Oh okay. Ill look into that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start an answer, but this isn't going to be a complete answer because I'm not yet sure of the complete question.  However, I can help.

```
TimePoint createdTime = system_clock::time_point{hours(h) + minutes(m)};
```

(I've clipped the `std::chrono::` qualifiers so that this is easier to read and discuss)

This creates a time stamp that is 1970-01-01 hh:mm:00 UTC.  In a nutshell, `system_clock::time_point` is measuring the duration of time (in some units like microseconds or nanoseconds) since New Years 1970, UTC.  Technically the above is an approximation, `system_clock` doesn't count leap seconds, but we can (and should) ignore that detail for now.

This:

```
tm timeExtracted = *localtime(&tt);
```

is going to introduce UTC offset corrections based on your computer's setting for the local time zone.  The time zone adjustment rules are (hopefully) going to be based on what was in effect in 1970 in your area.

There exist techniques and libraries for taking a `system_clock::time_point` and breaking it up into fields such as `{year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds}`.  But that conversion also depends on if you want these fields in UTC, local time, or some other arbitrary time zone.

And the *very* first step is to apply the UTC offset associated with some time zone if desired.  It may be that your `{h, m}` input needs a UTC offset adjustment prior to putting them into `system_clock::time_point` if the intent is that `{h, m}` represent local time instead of UTC.

### Update: Store hours example

This example will use my [free, open-source time zone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), because I feel it is much easier to work with and allows for more readable and expressive code.

This example takes as input a `system_clock::time_point` and compares it to a list of open/close times for each day of the week and determines if the input time is inside or outside of those time-of-day ranges for the weekday associated with the input time `t`.  The store hours are presumed to be stated with respect to the store's local time zone, which is also the current time zone set for the computer running this code.

```
#include "date/tz.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>

bool
is_store_open_at(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    struct day_schedule
    {
        weekday wd;
        minutes open;
        minutes close;
    };

    // hours are expressed in terms of local time
    static constexpr day_schedule store_hours[]
    {
      // week day   open-time   close-time
        {Monday,    0h,                0h},  // closed all day
        {Tuesday,   8h,               18h},
        {Wednesday, 8h,               18h},
        {Thursday,  8h,               18h},
        {Friday,    8h,               18h},
        {Saturday,  8h,         15h+30min},
        {Sunday,    9h+30min,         15h}
    };

    auto local_tp = current_zone()->to_local(tp);
    auto local_day = floor<days>(local_tp);
    auto local_time_of_day = local_tp - local_day;
    weekday local_weekday{local_day};
    auto ds = std::find_if(std::begin(store_hours), std::end(store_hours),
                           [local_weekday](day_schedule const& x)
                           {
                               return x.wd == local_weekday;
                           });
    assert(ds != std::end(store_hours));
    return ds->open <= local_time_of_day && local_time_of_day < ds->close;
}

#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << is_store_open_at(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << '\n';
}
```

The function begins by defining some handy data structures to store the open and close times for each day of the week.  The `open` and `close` members of `day_schedule` measure "minutes since midnight" in local time.

The input time `tp` is in terms of UTC, since its type is `system_clock::time_point`.  This is not currently specified by the C++ standard, but will be for next year's C++20.

<del>`zoned_seconds` is used to convert the UTC time `t` into local time according to the computers time zone setting obtained by calling `current_zone()`.  I've truncated `t` to seconds to simplify some of the syntax.  This isn't strictly necessary.</del>  I've edited to use slightly simpler syntax to eliminate the `zoned_seconds`.  `zoned_seconds` can be really useful in other examples, but in this one was more trouble than it was worth.  `auto local_tp = current_zone()->to_local(tp)` is a simpler way to translate UTC to a local time point.

`local_tp` is a `chrono::time_point` that is considered "local time", and is distinct from the family of `chrono::time_point`s associated with `system_clock`.  The advantage of doing this is so that if local time and UTC time are accidentally mixed, it is a compile-time error.

`local_days` is simply `local_tp` truncated to `days` precision.  It is still a `chrono::time_point`, just a coarse one that points to the beginning of the day as described by the local time zone.

The time duration since the local midnight is simply `local_tp - local_day`.

The day of the week (as defined by the local time zone) can be obtained by converting `local_day` to type `weekday`.  This is the local day of the week associated with `tp`.

Now it is a simple matter to search `store_hours` for the entry that matches `local_weekday`.

The store is open if `local_time_of_day` is at or past the `open` time and has not yet reached the `close` time.

If the "store hours" are specified in UTC instead of local time, then this program simplifies somewhat, but is still similar.

Comment: Okay thank you so far! It clears this up a bit already. Thank you for your help! Im honestly not done understanding this, yet. Right now I have no time, so Id like to ask and specifiy the question later this day (when I have time). But up to this point: Thank you already!!!

Comment: Okay now I revisited. I understand what you mean now. Can I get rid of that offset time from `*localtime(&tt)`? I really only need a time based on the weekday, hours and minutes (maybe seconds). Or maybe I should ask this: Can you give me a code example of the thing I want to do? Make a start point, make an end point, check whether the current time is in between it and do something when its inside that range? Maybe that makes it  a bit clearer, and maybe I can work or ask better questions after I've seen some example code (which I havent found in the web, btw. (for such an action))

Comment: Like store open hours?  And does that mean that the input times are expressed in the local time zone as opposed to UTC?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed! I still need to understand it a bit more throughoutly, but I guess this is it. Thank you so much! May I ask again, if there is any question?

Comment: Of course!  You can also open issues here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/issues  And here: https://gitter.im/HowardHinnant/date?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge